# How to check if the are app's dependencies on platform (feedesktop, gnome, kde) from Flathub in order to remove them safely?

Tags: package-management, dependencies, flatpak

The place taken by flathub/flatpak repo (`/var/lib/flatpak/repo`) is insane, this issue is known.

I already uninstalled applications unused or replaced by `snap` repo equivalent when they exist. Unfortunately it did not clean as much as I wished.

While using the command `flatpak list --show-details` it shows some lines with comment about deprecation:

```
Ref                                      Origin  Active commit Latest commit Installed size Options 
org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/20.08    flathub 0b445d980a32  -             746,9 MB       system,runtime,eol=org.freedesktop.Platform 20.08 is no longer receiving fixes and security updates. Please update to a supported runtime version.
...
org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/41             flathub 399027e27485  -             775,4 MB       system,runtime,eol=The GNOME 41 runtime is no longer supported as of September 17, 2022. Please ask your application developer to migrate to a supported platform.
...
org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.14             flathub 1339af97dfb3  -               1,0 GB       system,runtime,eol=The KDE 5.14 runtime is no longer supported and does not receive security updates. We strongly recommend migrating to a supported runtime.
...
org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.15             flathub f2a7e3e29086  -               1,0 GB       system,runtime,eol=We strongly recommend moving to the latest stable version of the Plaform and SDK.
```

So how can I be sure to uninstall those without compromising the stability of other elements ?

Comment: @user535733 Now that I look more closely, I think you're right. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @user535733 Checking dependencies is a flatpak's shell command ?